# UICollectionViewController edit

Tags: ios6, uicollectionview

I can use `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;` to get `UITableViewController` in editable state by pressing edit button on navigation panel.

How to make such behaviour for `UICollectionViewController`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution:**

I added button with delete image to the cell,
and then in `cellForItemAtIndexPath:`

```
...
if (self.editing) {
    cell.deleteButton.hidden = NO;
}else cell.deleteButton.hidden = YES;
...
```

Reload data on edit button touch:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    _fetchedResultsController = nil;
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
```

Button trigger delete method:

```
- (IBAction)deleteTour:(UIButton *)sender{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = nil;
    indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:[self.collectionView convertPoint:sender.center fromView:sender.superview]];
}
```